# How do I remove a subset of polygons from a Large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame using a string search, in R?

Tags: r, string, subset, polygon, spatial

I have a spatial file in R, that contains all the [area units](https://koordinates.com/from/datafinder.stats.govt.nz/layer/25743/) for New Zealand. I have downloaded it in NZGD2000 format. In this file I have irrelevant geographic details, such as the Oceanic regions. I have managed to remove those from my data by simply removing those polygons with higher than a certain value.

```
library("dplyr")
library("rgdal")
library("rgeos")

NZAreas <- readOGR("[FILEPATH]/area-unit-2013.shp")
#remove the areas that are offshore
NZAreas@data$AU2013_V1_ <- as.numeric(as.character(NZAreas@data$AU2013_V1_))
NZAreas <- NZAreas[NZAreas@data$AU2013_V1_ < 614000,]
```

I have the problem that the area units include inlets and inland water. I can't remove those in the same way as I removed the coastal units, as the area unit values are not continguous. The `@data$$AU2013_V_1` contains the labels for the area units. All the area units I wish to remove have the label starting with "Inlet" or "Inland Water".

I can't work out how to remove these polygons from the data.
First I tried without the dataframe name in front of the `@data`:

```
NZAreas <- NZAreas[!grepl("Inlet", @data$AU2013_V_1),]
Error: unexpected '@' in "NZAreas <- NZAreas[!grepl("Inlet", @"
```

and then I tried:

```
NZAreas <- NZAreas[!grepl("Inlet", NZAreas@data$AU2013_V_1),]
```

That second code runs but does not remove the polygons; it does not seem to do anything to the `Large SpatialPolygonDataFrame`. I checked the dataframe I constructed off `NZAreas` and there are Inlet and Inland Water rows. How do I remove these polygons?

Comment: I wonder if you can use polygons from other data source like GADM. Then, you would not have to go through the process you are doing.

Comment: It's really hard to help you without having a reproducible example. Can you contrive a  small data set which demonstrates your issue?

Comment: The link contains the data I am using.

Comment: @jazzurro I had a look at the GADM website, and it doesn't contain the polygons I need for other mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. It removed  49 areas containing "Inlet" in label and 15 areas having "Inland Water" in label.

```
> dim(NZAreas)
[1] 2004    5
> NZAreas=NZAreas[!grepl("Inlet", NZAreas$AU2013_V_1),]
> dim(NZAreas)
[1] 1955    5
> NZAreas=NZAreas[!grepl("Inland Water", NZAreas$AU2013_V_1),]
> dim(NZAreas)
[1] 1940    5
>
```